# using pyinstaller to compile pickled sklearn model to EXE file without import Sklearn module

Tags: python, import, scikit-learn, pyinstaller, pickle

I'm using pickle to load voting regressor model so I don't want to import pandas, sklearn at all
(to minimize file size)

When I run my code at Spyder, it works well.

The problem is when I warpped my code to EXE using pyinstaller and execute EXE file,
it occurred error below

---

Traceback (most recent call last) :
File "test.py", Line 92, in 
ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'sklearn'
[11316] Failed to execute script test

I thought my pickled model file included sklearn, but seems it's not and didn't work when EXE file form.

Is there any way to execute file without importing sklearn module?
file size is 18.5mb now, but if import sklearn, file size will be 150~250mb.
I don't want to make my file so huge...

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
import pickle
import sys, os
import math

sys.setrecursionlimit(5000)

title = 'Calculation'
sg.theme('Default')

def start_menu () :
   # 16 Columns 
    start_layout = [ [sg.Text('Input your data',size =(30,2), font=20)],
                 [sg.Text('Input 1', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))],     # 0
                 [sg.Text('Input 2', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))],     # 1 log1p
                 [sg.Text('Input 3', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))],          # 2
                 [sg.Text('Input 4', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))],  # 3
                 [sg.Text('Input 5', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 4
                 [sg.Text('Input 6', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 5 log1p
                 [sg.Text('Input 7', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 6 
                 [sg.Text('Input 8', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 7 
                 [sg.Text('Input 9', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 8 log1p
                 [sg.Text('Input 10', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 9
                 [sg.Text('Input 11', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 10 log1p
                 [sg.Text('Input 12', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 11 log1p
                 [sg.Text('Input 13', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))],  # 12
                 [sg.Text('Input 14', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 13
                 [sg.Text('Input 15', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))], # 14 log1p          
                 [sg.Text('Input 16', size=(24,1)), sg.InputText(size=(10,1),pad=(40,10))],  # 15
                 [sg.Button('Confirm')] ]
    window = sg.Window(title, start_layout)
    event, value = window.read()
    window.close()
    return event, value 


def result_menu (pred_value) : 
    
     result_layout = [[sg.Text('Prediction Value is '+str(pred_value), size=(30,2))],
                     [sg.Button('ReCalculation')],
                     [sg.Button('End')] ]
     window2 = sg.Window(title, result_layout)
     event, value = window2.read()
     window2.close()
     return event, value 
                
# Skew Columns : 1, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14
skew = [1, 5, 8, 10, 11, 14]

     
while True : 
 
    while True :
        
        event, values = start_menu()
        
        num = 1
    
  #      print(values)
        for i in range(16) :
            if values[i] == '' :
                sg.popup_timed('Check your input', auto_close_duration=5)
                num = 0 
                break 
            
        if num == 1 : break # go to Calculation
        
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED : break 
    val = []
    for i in values.values() :
        val.append(float(i))
        
    # loading Data / Model
    
    def resource_path(relative_path) :
        if hasattr(sys, '_MEIPASS') :
            return os.path.join(sys._MEIPASS, relative_path)
        return os.path.join(os.path.abspath("."), relative_path)
    
    if __name__ == "__main__" :
        model_file = resource_path('vt_model.pkl') # Voting Regresson
        table_file = resource_path('table.pkl')    # DataFrame (for Prediction)
        scaler_file = resource_path('scaler.pkl')  # Minmax scaler
    
    model = pickle.load(open(model_file, 'rb'))
    table = pickle.load(open(table_file, 'rb'))
    scaler = pickle.load(open(scaler_file, 'rb'))
    
    # DataFrame /  log1p 
    for i,j in enumerate(table.columns) :
        if i in skew : table[j] = math.log(val[i] + 1)
        else : table[j] = val[i]
    
    # MinMax 
    scale_table = scaler.transform(table)
    for i,j in enumerate(table.columns) : 
        table[j] = scale_table[0][i]
    
    # Predict
    sg.popup_timed('   Predict...   ' , '                       ', auto_close_duration=2, button_type=5)
    pred_value = model.predict(table)
    pred_value = int(pred_value.round(0))  # np.round
    
    event, values2 = result_menu(pred_value) 
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED or event in ('End') : break
```

Comment: So you are trying to un-pickle a pre-trained model instance?

Comment: Yes. Voting Regressor is already trained and I just want to un-pickle and use it for prediction

Comment: You shouldn't need to import sklearn. A pickled class instance should come with all its methods in tow. Unless you are trying to perform some operation that is not a part of this class.

Comment: I thought it worked with no problem and actually worked at script. But module error is occurred when it is EXE file form. I don't know why..